# Fingerprint recognition in Vista x64

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, 64-bit, fingerprint

I own a HP MobileWorkstation running Vista x64 Business, Serice Pack 1. The notebook has a personal identification device for fingerprints. Since I installed the 64-bit version of Vista, it is not recognized any longer.

I use AuthenTec Inc. AES2810 drivers and VeriSoft myIdentity application. What do I have to do to regain fingerprint recognition?

Comment: Quick comment (not completely familiar with x64 Windows): Are the drivers certified for 64-bit? I don't remember if they have to be any more.

Comment: AuthenTec has them listed as suitable for Windows 64bit. I do not get errors from Windows installing them, and in Device Manager it says: This device is working properly.

Comment: You may want to test it like the MythBusters did back in 2006, using a wet photo copy of your fingerprint -- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAfAVGES-Yc

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is silly?  WHatever happened to a good old 14 character password..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need the Credential and Fingerprint Manager from HP's [support](http://support.hp.com) website (also found on the OEM driver and application CD/DVD).

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. It's interesting that HP for the 8530w recommend Authentec with VeriSoft, but has Credential and Fingerprint Manager on the CD.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP HDX, Vista 64bit. Installed is the driver from Validity Sensors. The app is DigitalPersona Personal. The sensor works fine with that.