# Microsoft Fingerprint Reader on Windows 64-bit (Vista or Windows 7)

Tags: drivers, 64-bit

I think I know the answer to this question, but I have to ask anyway.  I am running 64-bit Windows (Vista or Windows 7) and I cannot get 64-bit drivers for the [Microsoft Fingerprint Reader](http://www.Microsoft.com/canada/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/features/fingerprint.mspx).  It is really annoying that Microsoft continues to sell a product for which they refuse to fully support.  This is the only piece of hardware that I cannot use on Windows 64-bit edition.

[This is the most comprehensive thread](http://social.technet.Microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itproVistahardware/thread/503021b8-fc19-4152-b4ba-ece02082ad97) I have found to date.  I would even accept the fact that it is a hardware limitation, but I just don't understand why they don't sell an upgraded version that supports 64-bit.

Comment: Fun facts about the MythBusters using a moistened regular photocopy to fool such devices at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA4Xx5Noxyo :-)

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/595/fingerprint-recognition-in-vista-x64

Comment: To anyone with this situation, i just called (4/4/11) the supplemental parts line, and they are sending me a check! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mswanson/archive/2004/12/03/274170.aspx?Pending=true) post by Mike Swanson the following is Microsoft's official statement in this regard. I recall being told about this during Tech-Ed last year as well.

> *Thanks for your interest in Microsoft Hardware products.
>
>   The Fingerprint Reader is no longer being manufactured by Microsoft but we recognize it may still be available from retailers and resellers.  The product runs on 32-bit versions of Windows XP and Windows Vista. Microsoft will not be releasing any updates for the product to run on 64-bit versions of Windows XP or Windows Vista. The product is not supported on Windows 7 (32-bit or 64-bit).  To ensure this is clear to our customers, the product will not install on Windows 7 (the user is warned that the application will not run). If you currently use the Fingerprint Reader and are unable to use your product with 64-bit versions of Windows XP or Windows Vista or the Windows 7 beta release, please visit the following Web site for assistance:*

Source [Microsoft Support](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/support/fingerprintreader.mspx).

Comment: While the rebate answer is awesome, this response most accurately answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Microsoft is offering users a refund](http://forums.slickdeals.net/showthread.php?threadid=1351761) due to the fact that they will not be providing 64-bit drivers.

Comment: That rocks! I will have to try that out!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a working solution for 64-bit Windows and Microsoft Fingerprint Reader:

http://teknogods.com:8081/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8653

Just register and download files...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Annnnnnd... The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

That might be the only piece of hardware you **own right now** that you can't use with the 64-bit edition, but certainly is not the only piece out there. Because of Microsoft's increased certification requirements for 64-bit drivers, you might have a hard time down the road as well...doing the research beforehand will save a lot of trouble (and perhaps convince you to stick with the 32-bit system for now).

Comment: Sure, but this is branded as a Microsoft product!  Don't you find it a little ironic that they aren't supporting their own hardware on their own OS?  Switching back to 32-bit is out of the question, I need support for at least 4GB of RAM :)

Comment: You can do 4GB...just not any more :) I agree it's ridiculous - but it's by no means purely a Microsoft-based problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use the discontinued Microsoft Fingerprint Reader with Vista 64 bit or Windows 7 64 bit Operating Systems now or in the future. Therefore Microsoft is issuing a full refund, all you have to do is call Microsoft Supplemental Parts line (US only) at 1-800-360-7561. You will be asked to provide the unique PID # on the back of the unit and your mailing address so they can issue your refund check. Be aware, PID #'s are unique and will be used to confirm that a refund has not already been issued.